# When will NVidia fully support Wayland (Ubuntu 17.10)?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 17.10, wayland

I was wondering if there is an ETA on when NVidia will fully support Wayland (if not already)?

I have the latest proprietary driver installed (GeForce 940M 390.25 driver) however, I have to set the GPU (prime-select) to Intel in-order to login (otherwise need to fix using tty2). I assume this is because the NVidia driver still does not support Wayland. I do all of my GPU intensive activities on Windows however, still would like the option in Ubuntu 17.10 to use the better-performance NVidia GPU.

Comment: Good question, that should have been directed at Nvidia. We have no way to know when, untill they have a public announcement. Also, it is doubtfull wayland will perform better in a short term future, and by the time it does, your card will be obsolete. :~)

Comment: It won't be really obsolete. It will be still a great improvement switching to nvidia in two years :-)

Comment: I've been using Wayland since Ubuntu 17.04 with nouveau and it's actually performing quite well for me - but I am stuck with some very specific software choices (that just happen to be what I prefer). EG: GDM3 and Gnome3.

The login issue you are having is absolutely due to incompatibility. Install the nvidia driver, switch to LigthDM, and run your window manager with Xorg/X11 and you should be fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

By accident, trying to fix screen tearing when using latest Nvidia driver in X.org, when I rebooted noticed that it rebooted into Wayland (tested with `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`). Idecided to try `prime select query`, I got: `nvidia`.

**The Solution:**
`sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/zz-nvidia-modeset.conf`
add options "**nvidia-drm modeset=1**" and save.
Run `sudo update-initramfs -u`

**check:**
`sudo cat /sys/module/nvidia_drm/parameters/modeset`
Should say `y` for `modeset=1` then,
`xrandr --verbose` 1st section, (the laptop display), should show `PRIME Synchronization: 1`

*Note:* Nvidia-settings still do not open even with `xhost +local`. `ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system`